# TableView not display the array datas

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!{
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            //tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var data = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        data = ["data1","data2", "data3"]
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.lbl?.text = data[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile... Is that your question? Or, are you not posting the actual code you are using?

Comment: I add just the important parts of the code that i try some solutions on it. Of course i have other necessary tableview functions.

Comment: OK - well, the *"important parts of the code"* ***are wrong!***. You need to post your actual code, otherwise people are just guessing at what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @DonMag I tried to add but somehow it gives error and i couldn't edit so it is emergency i just sent like this

Comment: Did you design your cell as a Prototype in Storyboard? If so, did you write a `class` for it? If so, what's the name of that class?

Comment: @DonMag yes i design. I give identifier as "cell" and class is TableViewCell

Comment: Did you also write a custom class for it? That would start `class MyCell: UITableViewCell`

Comment: @DonMag yes i write and it is class for that myCell

Comment: see my answer for a complete (basic) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you going, this is all the code you need:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    var data = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data = ["data1","data2", "data3"]

        // set the table view's dataSource
        myTableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

        cell.lbl?.text = data[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

}
```

This assumes that you

- created a cell prototype in Storyboard
- assigned its Custom Class to `MyCell`
- gave it an identifier of "myCell"
- added a label to it and connected it to `@IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!`

Comment: yes it is work, i think the problem was about classes i change as you did, and it works.Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to set delegate and you have not used code properly.

```
@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
var data:[String]!{
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    data = ["data1","data2", "data3"]

}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.lbl?.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

**Note:** if your cell is a nib file then register your cell in viewDidLoad before setting delegate=self

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "nibname", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

Comment: your cell is a nib file?

Comment: Yes i use tableViewCell class

Comment: It gives an error. "reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <- with name 'TableViewCell''" But i have this class why it gives error?

Comment: you have .swift file or .XIB file?

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

to ViewDidLoad()
And add

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

Below dataSource

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
```